# How to write custom validation error on mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Any idea how can I provide custom validation error on mongoose schema for unique values(unique:true).
I found here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html 
but in that they did not mention for unique values(unique:true)

I have tried so far. here for unique value it does't work.

`departmentId: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'cannot be empty'],
        unique: [true, 'already exist']
},`

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose, the `unique` option for schemas is `not a validator`. It's a convenient helper for building MongoDB unique indexes.  Please check this [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator) for more info.

Also, you can use [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) for your operation.